# What type of curve is $\left|\dfrac{x}{a}\right|^{z} + \left|\dfrac{y}{b}\right|^{z} = 1$?

Tags: geometry, terminology, plane-curves

In order to fit experimental data, I want to use a Cartesian equation which looks like:

$\left|\dfrac{x}{a}\right|^{z} + \left|\dfrac{y}{b}\right|^{z} = 1$

$a$, $b$, $c$, and $z$ can take any real value, except the impossible ones ($a = 0$ or $b = 0$, for instance).

First, **I look for a name for this equation** because I can't find more information about it if I can't name it. As far as I know, ellipsoids, paraboloids, or hyperboloids are not helpful here, since with those specific cases, $z = 2$, and that's all.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Superellipse / Lamé curve ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) / [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html)):

$\hskip 2.1 in$ [image: Superellipse for various exponents]

Comment: Great! It definitely looks like the shape I'm looking for and I now know the name associated with the equation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

It's referred to as a [Lamé curve](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Lame.html) or a superellipse.

Comment: [Here](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/lame/lame.shtml) is another nice page on these...

Comment: Thanks for the links and for the edit :-)