# "Nice" bijective continuous function from [0..1] to [0..1]

Tags: functions

I look for a "nice" function to map values from the input range $[0, 1]$ to output values in the same range $[0, 1]$, with the ability to tune a parameter $p$ to "bend" the function upwards away from $f(x)=x$.

A simple power function fits this requirment $f(x) = x^p$. When $p=1$ the function is not "bent upwards". Shown here with $p=0.3$:

[image]

I would prefer a function which is symetric with respect to the $(0,1):(1,0)$   $(f(x)=1-x)$ axis.
For this, $f(x)=\sqrt{x (2-x)}$ comes to mind, but this lacks a tunable parameter.

[image]

Can you recommend one or several functions from $[0, 1]\to[0, 1]$ with a tunable parameter as described above?

Comment: I had a similar problem some months ago and after a long search, I found this great threat, that hopefully also contains functions helpful to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65641/i-need-to-define-a-family-one-parameter-of-monotonic-curves

Comment: @ArnaudD. This is not symetric when p is not 0.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**superellipse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) $(1-x)^p+y^p =1$ is nice.

[image]

From the bottom, this shows $p=\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1, 2, 4$.
Also called **Lamé curve**.